# woocommerce - change product rating in loop from textual format to star display format

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display woocommerce products in loop, while doing this I noticed that the product review is displayed in textual format like "4.5 out of 5", but I am looking for a star type display [image]

And I am not sure if this is due to my theme, I googled but could not get proper suggesstions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your star-rating span is set to a text font. Change that in the following file: plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css:

```
.star-rating span {
    font-family: "star";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding bklynM also I am Sorry for the late reply. I checked your point and found it. right. In my plugin I am actually displaying product list using my custom code and as a part of this I had this `<span class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 product_maindetails_review woocommerce">
        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_rating(); ?>
                    </span>` but the output HTML markup div of rating is shown outside the span tags

Comment: my expectation is that the `woocommerce` class of span would help `.star-rating span` to catch up with the predefined styles and font in woocommerce.css

Comment: Not sure I follow you. woocommerce_template_loop_rating() gets the  loop/rating.php file. Do you mean your html and classes are not outputting as expected. Possibly you need to look at the "woocommerce_product_get_rating_html" hook. See here: http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_product_get_rating_html/ .  Look for clues in woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php and woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-recent-reviews.php files. If I've misunderstood,  let me know.

Comment: I figured the solution bklynM. It is all about including the class `woocommerce` and put the function `woocommerce_template_loop_rating()` in `<div class="woocommerce"></div>`. This has worked for me. I am editing your earlier answer a little.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The class .star-rating is wrapped inside the class .woocommerce. That being said, in order for you to display the stars instead of the actual average in text, you need to add the class .woocommerce to any of the parents of your .star-rating.

You can see the css in plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.scss

Add this code to get the rating in your loop and wrap the loop with the class .woocommerce.

```
<?php woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/rating.php' ); ?>
```

Example

```
<ul class="woocommerce">

    <?php  

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'order_by'  => 'post_id',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        );


        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>
        
        <li>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ); ?>
            <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/rating.php' ); ?>
            <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' ); ?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```